# Why not release memory after use NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's assume we create a new MacOS application with Xcode and adding some code inside the `[viewDidLoad]`.

The memory is not fully released after running. Why? How to release the memory?

Example code:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i=0;i<8000000;i++){
    [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(i, 0)]];
}
a = nil;
```

I can see the imformation about memory by a button which name is "show the debug navigator" by Xcode

Comment: Please describe how you measure memory comsumption.

Comment: How did you measure memory consumption??

Answer (score 2):

First let's have look on what you have done:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i=0;i<8000000;i++){
  [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(i, 0)]];
}
a = nil;
```

You create an array in the autorelease pool and you create a number of value objects in the autorelease pool. The autoreleased array holds the value objects.

A. As long as there is an autorelease pool in place, none of the objects will be released. The autorelease pool retains them. Therefore setting `a` to `nil` will not really help. As long as the autorelease pool retains an object, giving up a private reference cannot take the reference count to 0.

There are two techniques to avoid that:

a. As mentioned by @sunshine you can install a local autorelease pool. This will hold the objects instead of the more global autorelease pool, releasing the objects earlier. (But as said by @HotLicks, if should be placed outside the whole snippet.)

b. Do not create the objects in the autorelease pool.

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray new]; // new is ownership transfer
for(int i=0;i<8000000;i++) {
  CGPoint point = NSMakePoint( i, 0 );
  [a addObject:[[NSValue alloc] initWithBytes:&point withObjCType:withObjCType:@encode(CGPoint)];
}
a = nil;
```

B. It is possible that you still have "spooky" objects. Likely this is, because some value classes (i. e. `NSNumber`) does never free some objects considered to be re-used in near future. Maybe `NSValue` does the same, when using `valueWithPoint:`. That there is no corresponding `-initWithPoint:` is a pointer for that.

You can expect better information, if you tell us, how you measured the memory consumption. "ARC" is no answer to this question, because it is a memory management model, no memory measurement tool.

Comment: I can see the imformation about memory by a button which name is "show the debug navigator" by Xcode,Do you where is it? I can't post image.

Comment: I know the memory display in Xcode's debug navigator. Thank you. It displays the overall memory consumption of the app. Neither it is related to instance objects nor it is a pointer for memory leaks. (Even if you read that sometimes, it is still simply *wrong*.) There are several reasons that an app does not free memory reserved from the system at a concrete point in time.

Comment: The truth is that memory may not be reclaimed on system level even in presence of explicit/implicit releases and pools. Any hidden framework-level allocation may prevent pages to be returned to the system, thus memory would be marked as free but fingerprint may stay high for indefinite period. That doesn't mean that further allocations would grow the heap, as there are lots of framework/clib-level free space now.

Comment: @LERO That is how heap works in virtually any app, nothing to worry about unless memcheck tool shows otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ARC then you don't care about releasing at all. If you run this code under manual memory management mode then you still don't have to worry about the memory in this case because both array and the objects it holds are autoreleased. So this code is completely ok and can't cause any memory leaks

Comment: but the memory looks high and can't down,Why? Could you solve it ?

Comment: maybe because you're creating 8 millions of objects? how do you expect to keep memory low if you consume so much memory for your needs

Comment: You are really using a lot of objects. The memory gets down again, if your class instance is released from memory. You've written you use the for loop inside viewDidLoad. That means the code is executed inside a view controller. If you release all references to the view controller, the memory will be freed again. If you do this in the main view controller, the memory will be freed after closing the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @autoreleasepool:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    for(int i=0;i<8000000;i++){
        [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(i, 0)]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to add @autoreleasepool？
I has used the ARC，and what is the usefulness of the code?

Comment: You actually should use @autoreleasepool in situations like that - if you want to release them after (even with ARC). You are basically creating 8kk objects and after the loop they would be all cleaned, when you can add the block to release temporary objects after the autoreleasepool immadiately. Take a look: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: Even if `@autoreleasepool` is worthwhile in this situation (not clear that it is), it should be placed around the entire `for` statement (assuming it really is that limited in scope), vs each iteration.

Comment: @LERO ARC uses the ARP. So the idea of sunshine is pretty good. However you should place it outside the whole snippet.

Comment: @sunshine ARC is free to put release for an object just after it's strong container is set to nil. Simple test with custom class with NSLog() in dealloc and NSLog() after a=nil shows that current implementation actually does something leading to deallocation right in time, not waiting for the current pool to be drained.

Answer (score 0):

Using ARC doesn't guarantee that your objects will get released or tell you when they get released. Everything is done automatically behind the scenes.

When I'm saying that your objects are not guaranteed to be released think about retain(strong) cycles which they're still a reality even with ARC.

So, your code is fine at this point but if you want to force a release, as a colleague mentioned, embed your local objects into an `@autoreleasepool` block which will be drained when its execution finishes.